# "Failed to import" error . How i fix it

Tags: import, export, backup

When i am trying to import wordpress website facing this error how to fix it.

```
Import WordPress
Failed to create new user for info. Their posts will be attributed to the current user.
Failed to import product_type bundle
Failed to import product_visibility exclude-from-catalog
Failed to import product_visibility exclude-from-search
Failed to import product_type external
Failed to import product_visibility featured
Failed to import product_type grouped
Failed to import product_cat Men
Failed to import product_tag New Arrivals
Failed to import product_visibility outofstock
Failed to import product_visibility rated-1
Failed to import product_visibility rated-2
Failed to import product_visibility rated-3
Failed to import product_visibility rated-4
Failed to import product_visibility rated-5
Failed to import product_type simple
Failed to import product_cat Uncategorized
Failed to import product_type variable
Failed to import product_cat Women
Media “Placeholder Image” already exists.
Media “Placeholder Image” already exists.
Media “Placeholder Image” already exists.
Media “Placeholder Image” already exists.
Media “Placeholder Image” already exists.
Media “Placeholder Image” already exists.
Media “Placeholder Image” already exists.
Media “Placeholder Image” already exists.
Media “Placeholder Image” already exists.
Media “Placeholder Image” already exists.
Media “Placeholder Image” already exists.
Media “Placeholder Image” already exists.
Media “Placeholder Image” already exists.
Media “woocommerce-placeholder” already exists.
Media “WraptorLogo” already exists.
Media “WraptorLogo-ChromeGreen” already exists.
Media “img-signs-th” already exists.
Media “img-printing-th” already exists.
Media “img-clothing-th” already exists.
Media “img-signs-th-1” already exists.
Media “img-signs” already exists.
Media “img-signs” already exists.
Media “img-printingservices” already exists.
Media “img-vehiclewrap” already exists.
Media “img-wraps-th” already exists.
Media “img-designcreateinstall” already exists.
Media “img-vehiclewrap” already exists.
Media “img-home-header” already exists.
Media “img-smallcar” already exists.
Media “img-mediumcar-2” already exists.
Media “img-largecar” already exists.
Media “wraptor-icon” already exists.
Media “img-dualcab” already exists.
Media “img-4wd” already exists.
Media “img-SmallVan” already exists.
Media “img-LargeVan” already exists.
Media “img-sign-ACP” already exists.
Media “img-sign-corflute” already exists.
Media “img-sign-Aframes” already exists.
Media “img-sign-flagpole” already exists.
Media “img-sign-pullup” already exists.
Media “img-sign-cafebarrier” already exists.
Media “img-HighQualityPrint” already exists.
Media “smallcar” already exists.
Media “img-sign-corflute” already exists.
Media “img-signs-foampvc” already exists.
Media “img-signs-frostedwindows” already exists.
Media “img-signs-windowdecals” already exists.
Media “img-signs-wallgraphics” already exists.
Media “img-signs-builder” already exists.
Media “img-sisns-banner” already exists.
Media “img-signs-floor” already exists.
Media “img-printing-eco” already exists.
Media “img-clothing-StraightUp1” already exists.
Media “img-clothing-StraightUp1-1” already exists.
Media “img-clothing-StraightUp2” already exists.
Media “img-clothing-titan” already exists.
Media “img-clothing-ICQ” already exists.
Media “img-clothing-smiles” already exists.
Media “smallcar-1” already exists.
Page “Shop” already exists.
Failed to import “Jetpack t-shirt”: Invalid post type jp_pay_product
Failed to import “Jetpack t-shirt”: Invalid post type jp_pay_product
Failed to import “Jetpack t-shirt”: Invalid post type jp_pay_product
Failed to import “Jetpack t-shirt”: Invalid post type jp_pay_product
Media “MediumCar” already exists.
Media “LargeCar” already exists.
Media “DualCab” already exists.
Media “DualCab-1” already exists.
Media “4wd” already exists.
Media “SmallVan” already exists.
Media “LargeVan” already exists.
Media “img-printing-onthejob” already exists.
Media “img-printing-LJPGibson” already exists.
Media “img-printing-titan1” already exists.
Media “img-printing-titan2” already exists.
Media “img-printing-bruinbuilders” already exists.
Media “img-signs-floor-1” already exists.
Media “Img-clothing-dropbears” already exists.
Media “img-clothing-stingers” already exists.
Page “About” already exists.
Post “Behind the Product: Fedora Hat” already exists.
Page “FAQ” already exists.
Page “Contact us” already exists.
Page “News” already exists.
Page “Cart” already exists.
Page “Checkout” already exists.
Page “My account” already exists.
Page “Refund and Returns Policy” already exists.
Page “Communication preferences” already exists.
Page “Contact” already exists.
Page “About” already exists.
Page “Contact” already exists.
Page “Store” already exists.
Page “Vehicle Wraps” already exists.
Page “Wraps” already exists.
Page “Wraps” already exists.
Page “Signs / signwriting” already exists.
Page “Sticker Printing & Decals” already exists.
Page “Custom Clothing” already exists.
Failed to import “Popover Heavyweight Hooded Sweatshirt in Red”: Invalid post type product
Failed to import “Vintage Slub Cotton Crewneck T-shirt”: Invalid post type product
Failed to import “Long-sleeve Vintage Cotton T-shirt in Pink”: Invalid post type product
Failed to import “Garment-dyed Super Soft Slub Cotton Hoodie in Ash”: Invalid post type product
Navigation Menu “Header navigation” already exists.
Navigation Menu “Navigation” already exists.
Template “” already exists.
Template “” already exists.
Global Styles “Custom Styles” already exists.
Global Styles “Custom Styles” already exists.
Template “Home” already exists.
Template Part “Header” already exists.
Template Part “Footer” already exists.
Global Styles “Custom Styles” already exists.
Template “Wraps” already exists.
Pattern “Wrap Quote” already exists.
Pattern “Sign Quote” already exists.
```

Comment: looks like you didn't activate all the themes/plugins needed first and it's reporting it can't import those post types because they don't exist and it doesn't know what to do with them